# mouse position give wrong co-ordinates within group box

Tags: c#, windows, forms

When I give mouse  potion to label, it appear much down and left to the current mouse position.
Label inside one group box and group box contain more then 50% of the form area.
Group Box is compulsory here.
I'm trying with this code.

```
int xX, yY = 0;

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    xX = e.X;
    yY = e.Y;
    lbl.Left = xX;
    lbl.Top = yY;
}
```

Comment: A screenshot of what you are trying to achieve would be helpful here to clearly identify your problem. Reading your code whenever you move your mouse on the Form, the label's top-left aligns with the mouse cursor wherever it is over the form. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: plz check my comment I add pic there and try to explain the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to move the label within the boundaries of a panel, so you should add an event handler for the MouseMove event of the panel.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    panel1.MouseMove += panel1_MouseMove;
}

void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lbl.Location = e.Location;
}
```

Comment: One problem in this code. when mouse enter in group box lbl moving with mouse. But I want that lbl move when mouse key press then it will move with mouse and when mouse key up then it stop moving there. I'm trying with this code. See last comment plz

Answer (score 0):

```
public frmChequeFormat()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gbCheque.MouseMove += gbCheque_MouseMove;
    }
    bool mDown = false;
    private void gbCheque_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mDown)
        {
            label13.Location = e.Location;
        }
    }
    private void label13_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mDown = true;
    }
    private void label13_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mDown = false;
    }
```